# ngview adding partials preserving existing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `div` which is `ng-view`.

```
<div ng-view>Loading...</div>
```

Also I have a partial. Something like that:

```
<div ng-controller="p1">
  <div ng-controller="frm"></div>
  <div ng-controller="lst"></div>
</div>
```

Also I have some controller's code.

Is there any way to inject another similar structure with separate controllers and partials into my `ng-view`. So the picture should looks like

route: /

```
<div ng-view>
p1:
+-----+
| frm |
|     |
| lst |
+-----+
</div>
```

route: /abc

```
<div ng-view>
p1:     p2:
+-----+ +-----+
| frm | | abc |
|     | |     |
| lst | | def |
+-----+ +-----+
</div>
```

Comment: Okey, So I decided to solve that problem with
`<div ng-include src="marker"></div>`. In you `p1` controller you only need to set a `marker` to certain url (for instance, /js/app/views/partials/bla.html). All the controllers needed for functionality of newly included partial are already included. So everything works greate!

Comment: Hi, please add an answer to your question and accept it so this don't show again in the unanswered question section, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, So I decided to solve that problem with . In you p1 controller you only need to set a marker to certain url (for instance, /js/app/views/partials/bla.html). All the controllers needed for functionality of newly included partial are already included. So everything works greate!